# Implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_rekey' is invalid in C99

Tags: c, c99, sqlcipher

when i update Xcode from 8.3.3 to Xcode 9GM ,i used  pod 'FMDB/SQLCipher' before and it was OK. now  it says "Implicit declaration of function 'sqlite3_rekey' is invalid in C99" i try to solve this but it dose not  work , how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with `use_frameworks!` in CocoaPods. Please see this answer for a workaround using a `post_install` hook in your podfile.

https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/ios-11-xcode-issue-implicit-declaration-of-function-sqlite3-key-is-invalid-in-c99/2198/27